# Menu Button when Browser Is Resized

Tags: jquery, html, css

I only have CSS and HTML in my website, please tell me if jQuery is needed, or anything else... So, I have been trying to change the header to just a button that you can click on and make a vertical list, here is a good [example](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/). When the browser is full sized, the header is vertical, but when it is minimized, the header turns to a button (top right on the [example](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/).) and when clicked on, becomes a vertical list. Here is my code:

(BODY ONLY)

```
<body>
<div class="mainHeader">

    <div class="container">

        <div class="logo">
            <a href="#"><img src="Images/banner.png" width="300" height="100"></a>
        </div>

        <div class="nav">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Roster</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Our Sponsors</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
/*============================
======= Imported Fonts======== 
============================*/

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300,700);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700);

/*=========================
======= Body style ======== 
=========================*/

 body {
  color: #000305;
  font-size: 110%; /* Base font size: 14px */
  font-family: 'Montserrat', serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  left: 50%, margin-left: -(width of element/2);
  width: 100%;
}

/*=====================
======= Header ======== 
=====================*/

.mainHeader {
  background: #02236a;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.nav {
  float: right;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
}

    /*========================
    ======= Underline ======== 
    ========================*/

    .nav ul li {
      position: relative;
      color: #000;
      text-decoration: none;
      float: left;
      margin-right: 75px;
      margin-left: 55px;
      padding-top: 25px;
    }

    .nav ul li:hover {
      color: #000;
    }

    .nav ul li:before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 2px;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      background-color: #fff;
      visibility: hidden;
      -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
      transform: scaleX(0);
      -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
      transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    }

    .nav ul li:hover:before {
      visibility: visible;
      -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
      transform: scaleX(1);
    }

    .nav ul li a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #fff;
    }

/*============================
======= Miscellaneous ======== 
============================*/

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
}
```

Please ask if more information is needed, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have used the below code for adding the same functionality as you are asking may it help you. You have to use javascript with latest jquery fisrt add id to your nav div

```
 <div class="nav" id="navbar>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Roster</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Our Sponsors</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

add css

```
@media all and (max-width: 768px), only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) and (max-width: 1024px) {
    #nav {
    width: 100%;
}
#nav #menu-button {
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #000000;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
#nav #menu-button::after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    display: block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 2px;
    background: #000000;
}
#nav #menu-button::before {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    right: 20px;
    display: block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 3px;
    border-top: 2px solid #000000;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
}
```

}

and add javascript

```
(function ($) {

$.fn.menumaker = function (options) {

    var nav = $(this),
        settings = $.extend({
            title: "Menu",
            format: "dropdown",
            sticky: false
        }, options);

    return this.each(function () {
        nav.prepend('<div id="menu-button">' + settings.title + '</div>');
        $(this).find("#menu-button").on('click', function () {
            $(this).toggleClass('menu-opened');
            var mainmenu = $(this).next('ul');
            if (mainmenu.hasClass('open')) {
                mainmenu.hide().removeClass('open');
            } else {
                mainmenu.show().addClass('open');
                if (settings.format === "dropdown") {
                    mainmenu.find('ul').show();
                }
            }
        });

        nav.find('li ul').parent().addClass('has-sub');

        multiTg = function () {
            nav.find(".has-sub").prepend('<span class="submenu-button"></span>');
            nav.find('.submenu-button').on('click', function () {
                $(this).toggleClass('submenu-opened');
                if ($(this).siblings('ul').hasClass('open')) {
                    $(this).siblings('ul').removeClass('open').hide();
                } else {
                    $(this).siblings('ul').addClass('open').show();
                }
            });
        };

        if (settings.format === 'multitoggle') multiTg();
        else nav.addClass('dropdown');

        if (settings.sticky === true) nav.css('position', 'fixed');

        resizeFix = function () {
            if ($(window).width() > 768) {
                nav.find('ul').show();
            }

            if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
                nav.find('ul').hide().removeClass('open');
            }
        };
        resizeFix();
        return $(window).on('resize', resizeFix);

    });
};
})(jQuery);

(function ($) {
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#nav").menumaker({
            title: "Menu",
            format: "multitoggle"
        });

        $("#nav").prepend("<div id='menu-line'></div>");

        var foundActive = false,
            activeElement, linePosition = 0,
            menuLine = $("#nav #menu-line"),
            lineWidth, defaultPosition, defaultWidth;

        $("#nav > ul > li").each(function () {
            if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
                activeElement = $(this);
                foundActive = true;
            }
        });

        if (foundActive === false) {
            activeElement = $("#nav > ul > li").first();
        }

        defaultWidth = lineWidth = activeElement.width();

        defaultPosition = linePosition = activeElement.position().left;

        menuLine.css("width", lineWidth);
        menuLine.css("left", linePosition);

        $("#nav > ul > li").hover(function () {
            activeElement = $(this);
            lineWidth = activeElement.width();
            linePosition = activeElement.position().left;
            menuLine.css("width", lineWidth);
            menuLine.css("left", linePosition);
        },

        function () {
            menuLine.css("left", defaultPosition);
            menuLine.css("width", defaultWidth);
        });

    });


});
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have never used jQuery or JavaScript before, so how would I do this?

Comment: if you want to use only css then you can use @media screen but then you can only display your menu in vertical list but if you want to add a menu button and add event that controls your navigation then you have to use js..

Comment: i mean, how would I implement the jQuery?

Comment: Add <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script> in head section and add the above written javascript in the bottom of your code before body tag(you can also write in in seperate file and include it in your html file)

Comment: I've done this and it stays the same. Is it meant to only be for mobile devices?

Comment: Well thanks for that, but what I meant was like when you move your web browser, like [this](http://imgur.com/5ZS82ye)

Comment: you can adjust your media screen according to your requirement